# How to save a List<Object> and retrieve using Hive?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-hive

I have a Wallpaper App and it uses Firestore to store the wallpapers.

I want to use Hive to store a list of wallpapers from cloud firestore but how to save the List of Wallpapers and retrieve it later?

When I try to save the list I get this error:

> E/flutter ( 9995): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(199)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
>      E/flutter ( 9995): HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: Wallpaper. Did you forget to register an adapter?

Code:

```
class Wallpaper extends HiveObject {


  String date;
  String url;

  Wallpaper();

}

static Future<void> addWallpapers({@required String boxName, @required List<Wallpaper> wallpapers}) async {

    var box = await Hive.openBox(boxName);
    box.put(boxName, wallpapers);

    print("WALLPAPER ADICIONADO NO HIVE!");

  }

  static Future<List<Wallpaper>> getWallpapers({@required String boxName}) async {

    var box = await Hive.openBox(boxName);

    List<Wallpaper> wallpapers = box.get("latest");

    return wallpapers;

  }
```

Comment: Did you check this issue? https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/62

It might be related

Comment: Any Idea about getting Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<SourceStations>' I am trying to read list<CustomObject>

Comment: Convert it before, List<CustomObject> list = List<CustomObject>.from(dyamicList);

Comment: @djalmafreestyler Your last comment here just saved me from long hours of debugging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to anotate your object with @HiveType(). And have to register your object Hive.registerAdapter(WallpaperAdapter(), 0);.

And yet, do you have `part 'wallpaper.g.dart';` to generate the needed code?

EDITED:
First of all import the dependencies on your pubspec:

```
dependencies:
  hive: ^[version]
  hive_flutter: ^[version]

dev_dependencies:
  hive_generator: ^[version]
  build_runner: ^[version]
```

The `Hive.registerAdapter(MyObjectAdapter(), 0);` you should put inside your `main.dart` function. Right before runApp

Your HiveObject should have annotations like that:

```dart
@HiveType()
class Person extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0);
  String name;

  @HiveField(1);
  int age;
}
```

Put this command near your imports `part 'person.g.dart';` and run the code generation on your terminal. `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`.

Hive function with code generation, so this command will generate the file you need

Comment: Looks like the documentation needs serious improvements, I didn't see any example about that.

Comment: I agree with you. It should be more straight forward

Comment: Is it possible to you show me where should I use @HiveType ad Hive.registerAdapter on my code and explain me what's wallpaper.g.dart, so I can accept your answer?

Comment: For anyone who come after, @HiveType() now required a typeId.

Comment: @HiveField(0);  -----> This semicolon should be removed

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by including an actual ID on HiveType.
Like this:

```
  @HiveType(typeId: 0)
  class SoundSingle {

    @HiveField(0)
    final String name;

    @HiveField(1)
    final String fileName;

    @HiveField(2)
    int volume;

    SoundSingle(this.name,this.fileName, this.volume);
}
```

More HiveType models need to increment the number. So each value is unique ( and I guess sequential, but I did not test on that ) .

Answer (score 2):

**You need to perform the following steps:**

**Step 1:**
Add those dependencies on pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  hive_generator: ^1.1.3
  build_runner: ^[latest version]
```

**Step 2:**
Make the class like this

```
part 'wallpaper.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0, adapterName: "WallpaperAdapter")
class Wallpaper{

  @HiveField(0)
  final String date;

  @HiveField(1)
  final String url;

  Wallpaper({required this.date, required this.url});

}
```

**Step 3:** Run the command on terminal

```
1. flutter packages pub run build_runner build

                      or

2. flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

**Step 4:** Now register the adapter on *main.dart*

```
  void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(WallpaperAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox('myBox');

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**Step 5:** Now restart your application and let's enjoy