# Flutter Hive - Unhandled exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<SourceStations>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-hive

I am using this package https://pub.dev/packages/hive

I want to save and retrieve a list of custom objects in the hive.

I have tried to below approach

```
await Hive.openBox<List<SourceStations>>(stationBox); //Open box
Box<List<SourceStations>> sourceStationsBox = Hive.box(stationBox); 
sourceStationsBox.put(stationBox, listSourceStation); //Saving list of custom object as listSourceStation
//Should probably give lenght of list of custom object
logger.d('station box list length is ${sourceStationsBox.get(stationBox).length}');
```

But I am getting below error

> E/flutter (24061): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(199)] Dart
>   Error: Unhandled exception: E/flutter (24061): type 'List' is
>   not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast E/flutter
>   (24061): #0      BoxImpl.get
>   (package:hive/src/box/box_impl.dart:43:26) E/flutter (24061): #1
>   _SourceToDestinationPageState.openStationBox

I have tried checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413228/flutter-how-to-save-a-listobject-and-retrieve-using-hive) solution but not getting enough idea how to fix this.

Following are the hive version I am using

- hive: ^1.3.0
- hive_flutter: ^0.3.0+1
- hive_generator: ^0.7.0

Comment: what version of dart you are using?

Answer (score 9):

"Generic type parameters like `Box<List>` are unsupported due to Dart limitations."
This is mentioned in the author documentation: 
https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/boxes at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Hive doesn't support nested typecast like openBox<List> you can modify your code to this:

```
Box<List> sourceStationsBox = await Hive.openBox<List>(stationBox);
sourceStationsBox.put(stationBox, listSourceStation); //Saving list of custom object as listSourceStation
logger.d('station box list length is ${sourceStationsBox.get(stationBox).map((e)=> e as listSourceStation).toList().length}')
```

This will remove the error. Unfortunately there is no way around it due to Dart Limitations.

Whenever you want to get the list data just use the map function and cast the dynamic object to the object you created.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not using a `ValueListenableBuilder`, you can do it like this:

```
await Hive.openBox<List<SourceStations>>(stationBox); //Open box
Box<List<SourceStations>> sourceStationsBox = Hive.box(stationBox); 
sourceStationsBox.put(key, listSourceStation); // key is a string
logger.d('station box list length is ${sourceStationsBox.get(key).length}');
```